# Plugin with QT Creator and Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt

I would like to develop a selection-plugin in qgis. [image: Plugin created in QT Creator]

It doesnt run because there is a Problem with the python script. I can select the layer. 
However, I dont know how can i choose between "ZD", "RD", "DD" (which are the columns) and the "Year" (it is the value for selection)

Here the python-script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 SelectAttributes
                                 A QGIS plugin
 This plugin selects the attribute of the layers
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2016-04-12
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
        copyright            : (C) 2016 by C
        email                : 
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
# Import the code for the dialog
from select_attributes_dialog import SelectAttributesDialog
import os.path


class SelectAttributes:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'SelectAttributes_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = SelectAttributesDialog()

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&SelectAttributes')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'SelectAttributes')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'SelectAttributes')

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('SelectAttributes', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToVectorMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/SelectAttributes/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Attribute selektieren'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginVectorMenu(
                self.tr(u'&SelectAttributes'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())

    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)


        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

Comment: Hi, your question seems a bit unclear. Do you simply want to know which radio button (ZD, RD, DD) has been checked and which year has been selected, from the Python script? Or do you also want to know how to populate the comboboxes? Please add a few details about what you're trying to achieve (and what you already tried) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a function which populates the year comboBox each time a feature is selected. For this you'll need to add a line in **init** to call the function:

```
    self.dlg.comboBoxName.activated.connect(self.populate_years())
```

And then something like:

```
    def populate_years(self):
        years = []
        layerName = str(self.dlg.comboBox.currentText())

        layer = None
        for lyr in self.iface.legendInterface().layers():
            if lyr.name() == layerName:
                layer = lyr
                break

        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
             years.append(feature[x])

        self.dlg.comboBox2.addItems(years)
```

Where x is the index of the year value

For the radio buttons, in your run function:

```
if result:

    if self.dlg.buttonName1.ischecked():
        feature = "ZD"
    elif self.dlg.buttonName2.ischecked():
        feature = "RD"
    elif self.dlg.buttonName3 ischecked():
        feature = "DD"
```

And then call a function which takes the feature, layer and year as parameters and does whatever the plugin is supposed to do.

You can go to the SelectAttributesDialogue.ui file to find out the names of the radio buttons and the 2nd comboBox, or you can set tehm in QtCreator.